# In $\triangle CDF$, $CE$ $FB$ and $DG$ are placed in such a way that they intersects at point $H$. What is the value of $\frac{CH}{HE}$?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

***SOURCE:*** **Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2014**.

> The inner circle of $\triangle CDF$ touches $CD$, $DF$ and $FC$ at $B$, $E$ and $G$ points respectively. $CE$, $FB$ and $DG$ meets at the point $H$. The side $CD$ is divided into *$5:3$* ratio at the point $B$ and $CF$ is divided into *$3:2$* ratio at the point $G$. **What is the value of $CH:HE$**?

[image]

### My Attempt:

I was able to solve for the value of $CE$ with the help of trigonometry and all the length expressing by $x$, my calculation was that $CE$ $\approx$ $7.5216x$ (may be less or more) but I couldn't anyhow solve for the measurement of the length $HE$.

I will be very much gladful if anyone shows me how it can be solved with another method except trigonometry.

Comment: Is $A$ the center of the circle?

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't state that.

Comment: You should not label the center of the circle, especially when another point that is labeled and should be labeled is so close to it.

Comment: If it was labeled on the diagram on the competition, you don't need to repeat the mistake in the diagram in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Ceva Theorem,

${DB\over CB}\times{CG\over FG}\times{FE\over DE}=1 \implies {FE\over DE}={9\over 10}$

By Menelaus Theorem,

${CG\over FG}\times{FD\over ED}\times{EH\over CH}=1 \implies {EH\over CH}={15\over 19}$

Comment: Ceva Theorem states if three lines from vertices of a triangle meets at a center point, Then the product of the ratios of the divided sides, clockwisely(or counterclosewisely) multiplies to one. Menelaus Theorem states if a line cuts a triangle $ABC$ and intersects  $AB,BC,CA$ at $X,Y,Z$ then ${AX\over BX}\times{BY\over CY}\times{CZ\over AZ}=1$. If you are doing contest math, both Theorem should bee practiced and familiarized as they appear A LOT in national level contest problems,

Comment: Thank you for your kind information and instruction. I am a new beginner. So, I ain't familiar with these theorem but I will try to be acquainted with those theorem.